# Multibrand strategy in angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, css, angular, webpack

I have an use case which requires me to style an angular component several different ways. I am building seperate components (buttons, lists etc..) for other developers to use for their respective brand. For exampe, the same angular component could be used in 4 different sites (thus the component is exported as a module), but all sites require different css for this component.

What does angular 2/4 cli offer to accomadate this ?

Comment: Just ship all 4 stylesheets and pass a configuration parameter to the component in its implementation `[brand]="classname"`.

Comment: angular cli just offers to create a frame for you component and you have to write your own logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options :

### 1. Stay very basic with your template

Sometimes, you can do the job with only one DOM node. Build a VERY basic template which can be placed everywhere without affecting the DOM or the styling, and let your collegues create the rest of the template. Thus, the component will not depend on your template, your class names or any styles you would have created otherwise.

Of course, this is kind of an extreme solution :) !

### 2. Build your component as a wrapper with internal logic

Suppose you need to create a button. Instead of creating a template with a **button** element, you could also create a **div** element which contains all the logic you need (a *(click)* event handler for exemple). This  element is going to wrap a **button** provided by your collegues through transclusion. See below a possible **custom-button** component template :

```
<div (click)="handleClickEvent($event)">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

In the parent component you may imagine to have this :

```
<custom-button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
  </button>
</custom-button>
```

### 3. Use a classic html/css method

Give a template to your component and add class names to the DOM nodes in a way your collegues will be able to style them with a basic CSS.

It will be easy for you to prepare the component, but your collegues may be blocked by the names you choosed or the way the nodes are nested.

### 4. Give an entry point to provide styles used by the component template

For this, you will need an @Input() variable.

```
@Input() customStyles: any;
```

The variable will be provided to a HTML node through [ngStyles].

```
<button [ngStyle]="customStyles">Send</div>
```

The customStyles will necessarily be an object of a specific format (see official documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)).

In the parent template, you could provide the styles like this :

```
<custom-button [customStyles]="{'max-width.px': widthExp}"></custom-button>
```

The problem here is that you have to provide as much variables (entry points) as you need to style all DOM nodes of your template...

### 5. Give an entry point to provide a class

Like before, a variable holds a value provided by your collegues in the parent template. Here, you expect a string to be provided, corresponding to a class name.

```
@Input() customClass : string;
```

In your template, you are going to add this custom class to the outer div

```
<div class="someClass {{ customClass }}> <!-- Outer div -->
   <!-- Some DOM elements -->
</div>
```

Then, your collegues will be able to provide a class and to style all children elements in a CSS file according to the structure you create.

```
.bigButton {
  height: 500px;
  width: 1000px;
}

.bigButton > div {
  padding: 100px;
}

.bigButton:hover > div {
  // ...
}
```

In the parent template :

```
<custom-button [customClass]="'bigButton'"></custom-button>
```